# How to create and write to a file on sdcard with linux?

Tags: c, linux, sd-card, mmc

I want to create a file on `/dev/mmcblk0`, if it doesn't exist already, and then write to it. My question is how to check if there is already such file on the sdcard and then access it, does it show up like `/dev/mmcblk0/somefile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the command [mount(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) to mount the device first. That will cause the device's filesystem to be attached to your system's file-system, and therefore, makes you able to access files on it just like you normally do. For example:

```
mount /dev/mmcblk0 /home/yooo123/sdcard
```

If all goes well, you can read and write files to it using `fopen`, `fwrite`, etc.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("/home/yooo123/sdcard/file.txt", "w");
...
fprintf(fp, "Hello, SD Card!\n");
```

However, if you want to do all of that *from a C program*, look up the [mount(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mount) system call.

```
int mount(const char *source, const char *target,
      const char *filesystemtype, unsigned long mountflags,
      const void *data);
```

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/mmcblk0` points to a drive, so you will need to mount the drive first before you can see what files are available on it or create new files.